# JavaScript - iScroll - mousedown not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iscroll

We are using iScroll in our project, and some elements in it's scroll area have **mousedown** event attached.

On newest build of Google Chrome(*55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)*) mousedown event is never triggered and the reason is **pointerdown** event registered by IScroll.

Is there any way around it? I could of course use pointerdown instead of mousedown, but it is not supported in Safari, therefore I would need some dirty browser check.

```js
(function () {
  var scroll = new IScroll('#scroller');

  document.getElementById('testblock').addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownEventHandler);
  
  function mousedownEventHandler(event) {
    console.info(event.type, 'triggered.');
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#content {
  height: 5000px;
  background: white;
}

#testblock {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: silver;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cubiq/iscroll/master/build/iscroll-probe.js"></script>
<div id="scroller">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="testblock">Click me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the click parameter to the options object.

```
var scroll = new IScroll('#scroller', {
    click: true
});
```

Comment: Dunno, but it doesn't really help that one :/

Comment: Seems that cubiq has a workaround, for now. Since Chrome 55 adds pointer events and iScroll does not correctly support them. You need to add a small script statement to the head as a workaround... which is terrible, but there are other suggestions that seem to work in my tests as well. https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/1100

Comment: Updated your fiddle with a simple parameter as well...  https://jsfiddle.net/dck8med7/2/

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that this flag actually exist - *disablePointer*. This way it works, great!